# SELECT records until new value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

I have a table

```
Val | Number 
08    | 1 
09    | 1 
10    | 1 
11    | 3 
12    | 0 
13    | 1 
14    | 1 
15    | 1
```

I need to return the last values where Number = 1 (however many that may be) until Number changes, but do not need the first instances where Number = 1.  Essentially I need to select back until Number changes to 0 (15, 14, 13)

Is there a proper way to do this in MSSQL?

Comment: what version of SQL server do you using?

Answer (score 2):

Based on following:

> I need to return the last values where Number = 1
>
> Essentially I need to select back until Number changes to 0 (15, 14,
>   13)

Try (**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00d3e/3)** ):

```
select val, number 
from T 
where val > (select max(val)
              from T
              where number<>1)
```

**EDIT:** to address all possible combinations ([**Fiddle demo 2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39cf9/6))

```
;with cte1 as
(
  select 1 id, max(val) maxOne
  from T
  where number=1 
),
cte2 as
(
  select 1 id, isnull(max(val),0) maxOther
  from T 
  where val < (select maxOne from cte1) and number<>1
)
select val, number
from T cross join 
   (select maxOne, maxOther
    from cte1 join cte2 on cte1.id = cte2.id
    ) X
where val>maxOther and val<=maxOne
```

Comment: +1 - The only issue being if all values of `number` are `1`, since this won't return any rows. Oh, and on a different note, you should try the "Text to DDL" option on sqlfiddle. You just copy/paste the values from the question and it creates the sql code to generate the table. It's a time saver

Comment: I don't think this is quite correct.. What if the next inserted value is not a 1?

Comment: Thanks millions @Lamak. That is a nice feature which I never knew about. Spent ages creating tables.

Comment: @gvee: This answers the given situation but quite agree with you and that was why I quoted what he said.

Comment: @Kaf you appear to have missed a key part of the question: "I need to return the last values where Number = 1 ... **until Number changes** ..."

Comment: @gvee: I have updated the answer to address all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7d54/23**

### DDL

```
create table T(val int identity(8,1), number int)

insert into T values
(1),(1),(1),(3),(0),(1),(1),(1),(0),(2)
```

### DML

```
; WITH last_1 AS (
  SELECT Max(val) As val
  FROM   t
  WHERE  number = 1
)
, last_non_1 AS (
  SELECT Coalesce(Max(val), -937) As val
  FROM   t
  WHERE  EXISTS (
           SELECT val
           FROM   last_1
           WHERE  last_1.val > t.val
         )
  AND    number <> 1
)
SELECT t.val
     , t.number
FROM   t
 CROSS
  JOIN last_1
 CROSS
  JOIN last_non_1
WHERE  t.val <= last_1.val
AND    t.val > last_non_1.val
```

I know it's a little verbose but I've deliberately kept it that way to illustrate the methodolgy.

1. Find the highest `val` where `number=1`.
2. For all values where the `val` is less than the number found in step 1, find the largest `val` where the `number<>1`
3. Finally, find the rows that fall within the values we uncovered in steps 1 & 2.

Comment: @Kaf Your original answer didn't consider the edge cases and seemed to outright ignore part of the question. I commented appropriately. Now you have addressed these issues to provide a solution that works as per the question I have revoked my downvote. Isn't that what the voting system is for: to improve the quality and accuracy of answers?

Comment: I don't disagree with you. Sometimes it worth giving bit time, specially in complex cases like this. Anyways, now he has 3 answers and all addressing all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use window functions, something like this:

```
with cte as (
    -- generate two row_number to enumerate distinct groups
    select
        Val, Number,
        row_number() over(partition by Number order by Val) as rn1,
        row_number() over(order by Val) as rn2
    from Table1
), cte2 as (
    -- get groups with Number = 1 and last group
    select
        Val, Number,
        rn2 - rn1 as rn1, max(rn2 - rn1) over() as rn2
    from cte
    where Number = 1
)
select Val, Number
from cte2
where rn1 = rn2
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a650/11)</kbd>**

Comment: This is also very nice. +1

Comment: @Kaf and there's only one table scan, so it should be fast

Answer (score 0):

```
select val, count (number) from
yourtable
group by val
having count(number) > 1
```

The having clause is the key here, giving you all the vals that have more than one value of 1.

Comment: This will return no rows at all.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Teach me to try and answer questions on Monday mornings.

Comment: It's evening here so my engine is up and running!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common approach for getting rows until some value changes. For your specific case use *desc* in proper spots.

Create sample table

```
select * into #tmp from 
(select 1 as id, 'Alpha' as value union all
select 2 as id, 'Alpha' as value union all
select 3 as id, 'Alpha' as value union all
select 4 as id, 'Beta' as value union all
select 5 as id, 'Alpha' as value union all
select 6 as id, 'Gamma' as value union all
select 7 as id, 'Alpha' as value) t
```

Pull top rows until *value* changes:

```
with cte as (select * from #tmp t)
select * from
    (select cte.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn from cte) OriginTable
inner join 
    (
        select cte.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn from cte
        where cte.value = (select top 1 cte.value from cte order by cte.id)
    ) OnlyFirstValueRecords
on OriginTable.rn = OnlyFirstValueRecords.rn and OriginTable.id = OnlyFirstValueRecords.id
```

On the left side we put an original table. On the right side we put only rows whose value is equal to the value in first line.
Records in both tables will be same until target value changes. After line #3 row numbers will get different IDs associated because of the offset and will never be joined with original table:

```
LEFT           RIGHT
ID Value RN    ID Value RN
1  Alpha  1  | 1  Alpha 1
2  Alpha  2  | 2  Alpha 2
3  Alpha  3  | 3  Alpha 3
----------------------- result set ends here
4  Beta   4  | 5  Alpha 4  
5  Alpha  5  | 7  Alpha 5
6  Gamma  6  |
7  Alpha  7  |
```

The ID must be unique. Ordering by this ID must be same in both ROW_NUMBER() functions.